# 400 Bad Request You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port kubernetes pod

Tags: apache, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, shibboleth-sp

I am getting the error "**400 Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.**"

What I am trying to achieve is :

1.**Docker Run**
Docker Image which is using apache2 and Shibboleth both are running on port http(8090) & https(8443) respectively with self signed certificate. Running the image locally using the docker run it is working fine.
http://localhost:8090/ ----> working fine 
https://localhost:8443/Shibboleth.sso/Status ----> giving cert error but after accept and ignore working fine.
(Shibboleth service which is being accessed via apache2 000-default.conf  ProxyPass /Shibboleth.sso/ https://localhost:8443/Shibboleth.sso/Status)

2. Kubernetes Platform
   Below are the deployment,Service and Ingress created to access the same image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: demo
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  #replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <repository>public/demo-v1
        name: demo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8154
          name: demo-ui
        - containerPort: 8090
          name: http
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: https
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        resources:
           limits:
             cpu: 1000m
             memory: 8024Mi
           requests:
             cpu: 500m
             memory: 4096Mi 
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: demo-svc
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: demo-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8154
    name: demo-ui
    targetPort: 8154
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 8090
    name: http
    targetPort: 8090
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 8443
    name: https
    targetPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP     
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: demo-ing
  labels:
    app: demo
spec:
  ingressClassName: internal
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.example.com
  rules:
  - host: demo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-svc
            port:
              number: 8090
      - path: /demo-ui
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-svc
            port:
              number: 8090
      - path: /Shibboleth.sso
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-svc
            port:
              number: 8443
```

the default domain is using the https for *.example.com

```
when hitting **https://demo.example.com/ --> http://<pod-IP>:8090**  and working fine 
but when accessing the **https://demo.example.com/Shibboleth.sso/Status --- > http://<pod-IP>:8443**
```

And returning  "**400 Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please**"

I have tried multiple solutions via ingress annotations and apache2 redirect as well but nothing seems to help.

when doing redirect on apache2 it is not taking the localhost as variable.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8443$
 RewriteRule ^/Shibboleth.sso(.*) https://localhost:8443/Shibboleth.sso/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

not considering localhost and taking as dns.

Also tried to redirect at ingress level also which is giving 404 not found error.

Please help here !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try adding this annotation to your ingress file?

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, Thanks for the reply. 
I checked the above mentioned solution and "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS" alone helped here as my nginx controller is ignoring the rest of the two annotations.

To keep the http and https traffic I had to create two ingress for same deployment.

Comment: @gouravchauhan got it glad to here that it's working.

Comment: Adding nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS" to the ingress worked for me, thanks a lot. I have been looking for a solution for hours.